# drag and drop with raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

hello I am new to using the raphael javascript library I am trying to create a simple drag and drop; to be able to drag a clone shape from outside the canvas into the canvas R and I want to be able to delete the selected clone if the user clicks on it (user press delete on selected clone and clone gets removed) I also want to copy the clone and paste it. Here is my code:

```
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>Raphael Play</title>  
   <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.contextMenu.r2.js"></script>
   <style type="text/css"> 
   #canvas_container {   
           width: 500px;   
           border: 1px solid #aaa;   
        }   
    </style>
   <script>
window.onload = function() {
var nowX, nowY, w = 500, h=400, r=30, R = Raphael("canvas_container", w, h),
    c = R.circle(100, 100, r).attr({
    fill: "hsb(.8, 1, 1)",
    stroke: "none",
    opacity: .5,
    cursor: "move"
});

var clone=c.clone();

var start = function () {
    // storing original coordinates
    this.ox = this.attr("cx");
    this.oy = this.attr("cy");
    this.attr({opacity: 1});
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
    // move will be called with dx and dy
    // restrict movement of circle to within boundaries
   if (this.ox + dx <= w - r && 
       this.oy + dy <= h - r &&
       this.ox + dx >= 0 + r && 
       this.oy + dy >= 0 + r)
   {
        this.attr({cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy});
   } // else nothing
},
up = function () {
    // restoring state
    this.attr({opacity: .5});
};

clone.drag(move, start, up); 

};

// Create Context Menu

   </script>

</head>  
<body>  

    <div id="canvas_container"></div> 

</body>
```

Comment: Please give your questions more descriptive titles in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Every Raphael shape needs to be within a canvas; it can't be outside. You will need to make the canvas fill a larger area to include the other shapes, perhaps with the help of styles. I'm not sure if it'd work very well to have multiple Raphael canvases, since you'd need to create a new Raphael shape inside the other canvas, using the attributes of the other shape. You could do it, but I wouldn't do it. Also, be careful with using the delete button with JavaScript events, since that's used for navigation by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

1. I want to be able to delete the selected clone if the user clicks on it (user press delete on selected clone and clone gets removed)
2. I also want to copy the clone and paste it.

I suggest use the background image & process events (onkeypress) by PHP ajax. Then uplaod changed background image & make jquery.attr( "style", "back.jpg" ) change

BTW, thanks for example, i use it here:

http://softm.org.ua/projects/roundsel-v1/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice simple starting point for dragging objects. Have a look at the page source. I hope this helps you.

http://raphaeljs.com/touches.html